# Last inserted row with sqlite3 and C

Tags: c, sqlite, insert, key, datastore

I wrote a `key/value` store using `SQLite3` and `C`. The function `put_pair(key, value)` accepts an empty key as a correct key and in the `INSERT` query  the function `lower(hex(randomblob(16)))` generates a good key for this inserted row.

But I don't know how to retrieve this key and return it by my function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Or should I just generate a unique key (with another method) first, and then return it by my function once the INSERT query is well executed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`

Comment: Thanks Brian, like I said to vpit3833 below, I'd still need a SELECT to grab that key, and I need only one query per insert

Answer (score 0):

When the key is not known, try searching by values that match the given condition and return the rows.  Or if it is just the most recently inserted row that you are after, look at [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html).

Comment: Thanks vpit3833! I actually thought of rowid too, but that'd require another SELECT query after the INSERT one just to grab the key. And I'd like to run only one query per insert. I guess I should write a little uuid function or use a simple existing one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Query goes like this :

select * from emp where rowid = (select max(rowid) from emp);

emp = my table name

Hope will help needy ppl.....