# Simple random string generation function in C, please. Show me your art!

Tags: c, function, uuid

I'm working on a little (not so little actually) project in C (ref. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199946/last-inserted-row-with-sqlite3-and-c)) , and I need a little function in C that'd generate a unique and random string.

I need a small one that I can include as a utility function in a .c file.
Please help me with your brains, and show me how smart this could be done!

Thanks and a virtual BIG hug for the best solution :)

EDIT: (What I just said to msw below) I actually think that I just need a random string as a key (which would look like a uuid) and I thought that'd be done with timestamps or such. (I don't want to add a bunch of files to my project just for a random key generation)

Sorry for the confusion, everyone!

EDIT2: Thank you all for your input, I'll finally use the [OSSP uuid lib](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) with SHA-1 it looks easier to implement/integrate

Comment: Jens, true! I was wrong. see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel, there is probably a function that is already written on your platform of choice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Implementations

Comment: You're right msw, that's what I repeat very often. I actually think that I just need a random string as a key (which would look like a uuid) and I thought that'd be done with timestamps or such. (I don't want to add a bunch of files to my project just for a random key generation)

Comment: If you need unique **database** keys, that's a different problem with a different solution, please edit your question if this is the case. Timestamps are a bad basis for UUIDs, and [GU]UIDs are overkill for databases.

Comment: msw, well lets say that I need a random string. I won't use sqlite3 as a database. I was actually wrong, what I need is a random key (that'd be unique just for me in this very app)

Comment: That's what UUIDs are designed for, see my link in this answer, and you might want to consider switching to decaf ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another link for you - source of the [`libuuid`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git;a=tree;f=lib/uuid;h=37dfa59970505da872683880148d44b0a3ea505b;hb=efe0b401465a3ee836180614b5b435acbb84fc27) from the ext2fs.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this [internet draft](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~ejw/authoring/uuid-guid/draft-leach-uuids-guids-01.txt) which explains entire concept and try to implement one of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

What about a counter?

If you are not multithreaded, just hold the actual value in a `static` variable. (Since you need a string you would have to do some `sprintf` or so to get what you need.)

If you are in fact multithreaded, 
 when you produce your random key with `sprintf` glue the counter together with the thread and/or process id.

Answer (score 0):

What about [tmpnam](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tmpnam.html) ?